# How to convert Array to CVarArg?

Tags: swift

I have array of **values**. I want to pass in these **values** to string format using **CVarArg**.

```
let values = ["VAL1", "VAL2", "VAL3"]
let format = "Val 1 -> %1$@ Val 2 -> %2$@ Val 3 -> %3$@"
let varArg: CVarArg = // How to convert array to CVarArg?
let result = String(format: format, varArg)
```

How to convert array to **CVarArg**?

Comment: You can use `String(format: format, arguments: values)`, but I guess you question is getting array from variadic.

Comment: `let varArg = values as CVarArg` or simply `let varArg: CVarArg = values`